Extracting Data from Rows Based on Columns in R
I have the following problem where I know what I want to do but I am very unsure on how to code it in R. I have a data set (sample below), where the column names of column 9-16 are the values in column one. What I don't know how to do is to find the row(s) of the data frame that contain values in the 9th column that are greater than 0.4 but less than 1 subject to condition that the sex column has a value of female and extract the End_lat value of this row (i.e the value that would correspond to the second column). If there are multiple such rows I then want to choose 1 row that has the smallest year (8th column) value.
I would be very greatful to know if this is possible and how to go about coding this as I truly don't know where to start. Here is the data:
    data = structure(list(Sample = structure(1:8, levels = c("M20-1", "M20-2", 
"M20-3", "M20-4", "M20-5", "M20-6", "M20-7", "M20-8"), class = "factor"), 
    End_Lat = c(52.032459, 52.56744, 52.59194, 52.339827, 52.59194, 
    52.56744, 52.016708, 51.972729), End_Long = c(0.831109, 1.52194, 
    1.44322, 1.512589, 1.44322, 1.52194, 0.869783, 0.965756), 
    WRE = structure(c(1L, 5L, 8L, 2L, 7L, 6L, 3L, 4L), levels = c("M20-1", 
    "M20-4", "M20-7", "M20-8", "WRE0065", "WRE0066", "WRE0079", 
    "WRE0080"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1563926400, 
    1574294400, 1575676800, 1572307200, 1574208000, 1574380800, 
    1572912000, 1574380800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    Sex = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("FEMALE", 
    "MALE"), class = "factor"), Month = c(7, 11, 12, 10, 11, 
    11, 11, 11), Year = c(2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 
    2019, 2019), `M20-1` = c(NA, 0.280793517827988, 0.228535950183868, 
    0.246612563729286, 0.268684029579163, 0.239324256777763, 
    0.22248512506485, 0.169947937130928), `M20-2` = c(0.280793517827988, 
    NA, 0.323499649763107, 0.206507995724678, 0.298868834972382, 
    0.460075885057449, 0.213360741734505, 0.044871162623167), 
    `M20-3` = c(0.228535950183868, 0.323499649763107, NA, 0.167131945490837, 
    0.684527397155762, 0.343118369579315, -0.0143419550731778, 
    -0.021508164703846), `M20-4` = c(0.246612563729286, 0.206507995724678, 
    0.167131945490837, NA, 0.243042409420013, 0.260826170444489, 
    0.0600633434951305, 0.0738212391734123), `M20-5` = c(0.268684029579163, 
    0.298868834972382, 0.684527397155762, 0.243042409420013, 
    NA, 0.38673061132431, 0.065886601805687, -0.017916351556778
    ), `M20-6` = c(0.239324256777763, 0.460075885057449, 0.343118369579315, 
    0.260826170444489, 0.38673061132431, NA, 0.114707909524441, 
    0.0774253383278847), `M20-7` = c(0.22248512506485, 0.213360741734505, 
    -0.0143419550731778, 0.0600633434951305, 0.065886601805687, 
    0.114707909524441, NA, 0.150554329156876), `M20-8` = c(0.169947937130928, 
    0.044871162623167, -0.021508164703846, 0.0738212391734123, 
    -0.017916351556778, 0.0774253383278847, 0.150554329156876, 
    NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

Thank you for any feed back and help you can give, and apologies if the question is not clear I will clarify if this is the case.

What if there are multiple rows with the same year, e.g when the threshold is 0.25 instead of 0.4?

I would want to randomly select one of those such rows.

To choose a random one use sample(... , 1) around one of the given solutions. If you want a grouped by year output rather then just one value add some values to your example and @ mention that you need groups.

Thank you for your help, I very much appreciate it.

Not sure if I understand correctly what you want to do, but the way I understood it, this should work:
## select the rows where values in column 9 are more than 0.4 but less than 1
rows <- data[,9] > 0.4 & data[,9] < 1

# no such rows are in the sample
data[rows,]

# assuming that there are such values, select only the women
data[rows & data[,6] == "FEMALE",]

# getting the End_lat value for these
data[rows & data[,6] == "FEMALE",]$End_Lat


Thank you for your help. It works in the way I had in mind.

Onw way to solve your problem.
# Note: column 9 name is `M20-1`
with(data, End_Lat[which(`M20-1`> 0.4 & `M20-1`<1 & Sex=="FEMALE" & Year==min(Year))])
numeric(0)

numeric(0) means that there is no such a row in the data.
